# ChartJS xAxis label position

Tags: javascript, chart.js, vue-chartjs

I have a ChartJS that display the label as slanted when you resize the window to smaller size.

[image]

What I want to do is to lower the X-labels down a bit vertically so they are not as close to the base of the graph if possible.

After googling around, it looks like I can disable the tick display for x-Axis and use the option's animation to do this manually.  I tried to implement this in the following [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2jc13qwx/).

```
    animation: {
      duration: 1,
      onComplete: function() {
        var chartInstance = this.chart;
        this.data.datasets.forEach(function(dataset, i) {
          var meta = chartInstance.controller.getDatasetMeta(i);
          meta.data.forEach(function(bar, index) {

            var label = bar._model.label;
            var xOffset = bar._model.x;
            var yOffset = bar._model.y;
            ctx.fillText(label, xOffset, 420);
          });
        });
      }
    },
```

However, I can't get the label to scale properly when I resize the window.  Can you help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chart.js implements a `padding` property in the [`ticks`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/#tick-configuration) object for this:

> Padding between the tick label and the axis. When set on a vertical axis, this applies in the horizontal (X) direction. When set on a horizontal axis, this applies in the vertical (Y) direction.

Here's a working example with the x-axis labels offset 20px down from the line:

```js
new Chart(document.getElementById("chart"), {
  type: "bar",
  data: {
    labels: ["Blue", "Red", "Green", "Orange", "Purple"],
    datasets: [{
      data: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
    }]
  },
  options: {
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          padding: 20
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<div style="height:200px;width:200px">
  <canvas id="chart"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you it works... this is way more simpler, i actually tried this padding but I did not realize it has to be chartjs 2.7 or higher.  Thanks.